# Jackson - accept empty string on Object property

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have POJO like this

```
@Data
public class Tree {
   String id;
   Leaf leaf;
}
```

How to make, that my rest controller with RequestBody "Tree" will accept JSON request with empty String on property leaf, omitted it and treat as null. Example JSON Request

```
 {
      "id": "foo",
      "leaf": ""
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the `ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT` attribute of your `ObjectMapper` to `true`.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features#value-conversions-coercion) :

> Determines whether empty String value is accepted as null value for
>   regular POJOs ("beans") with data-binding: this can be useful when
>   dealing endpoints written in a language that has loose typing and may
>   represent missing objects as Empty Strings.

If you're using Spring Boot, you can [find details here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) on how to configure your `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Can I applied this solution only to specific class or property, not for full context ?

Comment: Spring will use the `ObjectMapper` it finds in the registered beans. But you still can do it manually : edit your method to accept `string` value, and create yourself an `ObjectMapper` inside, which will parse the string into a `Tree` (with `readValue` function).

Answer (score 2):

Configure the ObjectMapper as follows:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Jackson ObjectMapper to accept empty string as null. To do that simply add the following method in your configuration class.

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper mapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
    return mapper;
}
```